# Meteor cfs-s3 error with CollectionFS "FS.TempStore.Storage is not set"

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

im trying to use CollectionFS with cfs-s3 but im getting "FS.TempStore.Storage is not set: Install cfs-filesystem or cfs-gridfs or set it manually" when I try to upload an image, I followed this guide - https://atmospherejs.com/package/cfs-s3.

If I install either of then the image is uploaded to S3 however its also upload via that method as well, so the url attribute is not the S3 one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add either `cfs:gridfs` or `cfs:filesystem` to be used as a temporary store before the files are uploaded to S3. As long as one of these packages is present on your system everything should work.